# RDM Sockets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking

I've recently come across .NET's RDM Socket type (SocketType.Rdm) and its features sound very promising, sounding very much like a reliable connectionless protocol. However, I've found no examples of its usage, and little documentation on the protocol itself.

First of all, how do I instantiate a socket of this type? Specifying SocketType.Rdm in the socket constructor always seems to cause an exception. Secondly, is this protocol referred to by a different name outside of .NET? As I say, the protocol seems to undocumented despite it's promising feature set.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is [PGM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatic_General_Multicast). Here are some random links to MS forum bits:

- [devshed](http://forums.devshed.com/net-development-87/using-rdm-socket-in-c-229576.html),
- [ms](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/97fa4a07-1307-4c3c-b4b4-529a9beb677f/).

I have no idea about the maturity of .NET implementation.

Answer (score 2):

RDM sockets do support PGM. However PGM support is not installed on Windows by default, but as part of the MSMQ installation. If you have Windows 7, this is the command line that will prompt Package Manager to install the right components.

pkgmgr /iu:MSMQ-Container;MSMQ-Server;MSMQ-Multicast

Try running your socket after installing this and see if you still have the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

[Reliable Multicast with PGM and WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62277/Reliable-Multicast-with-PGM-and-WCF) is an interesting article over at codeproject on how to use RDM (PGM) sockets. It features both raw PGM sender/receiver classes and also builds on it by implementing WCF connectors for PGM